# How to connect dots with lines with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

**Solved!**

> Thank you @Gregor and @eipi10. I solved this problem by
>
> 1. Converting the dataframe to `long` format:
>
>    `dat.long <-poverty %>% gather(key, value, -Year)`
> 2. Filter out all the `NA`s:
>
>    `dat.long<-dat.long[complete.cases(dat.long), ]`
> 3. ggplot!

---

---

---

### Preface

Unlike [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404959/connecting-points-with-lines-in-ggplot2-in-r) questions, I have a quite odd data frame with several `NA` values:

[image: IMAGE 1]

When I `geom_line` them:

```
ggplot(poverty, aes(Year))+
  geom_line(aes(y = poverty$Poverty..BM.2002.....of.world.population., colour = "2002 Poverty"))+
  geom_line(aes(y = poverty$Extreme.Poverty..BM.2002.....of.world.population., colour = "2002 Extreme Poverty")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = poverty$Less.than.1.90..per.day..World.Bank..2015......of.world.population., colour = "2015 Poverty"))
```

I get discontinued lines:

[image: Discontinued lines]

There are SO posts suggesting plot points first, then connect them by `group`. I thought it is a good idea when I got something like this:

[image: Scatter plot]

### Problem

How do I connect the dots? (*note, I don't have `factor` class column in my dataframe, so I can't really do it by `group=`*)

**Desired output**:

[image: Desired Output]

### Side Request

How do I change the legend title?

Thank you!

Comment: Change your data to long format, use a single geom_line and a single geom_point. **Never** put `data$` inside `aes()`, use bare column names..

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. But I cannot find `as.long`, (I'm new to R), would you help me with that? I did some research and found a package called `reshape2` can do that, but I don't know how to actualize that for my case. Thank you, Gregor!

Comment: Long format example: `library(tidyr); dat.long = poverty %>% gather(key, value, -Year)`. This will stack all columns, except `Year`. There are lots of tutorials on `tidyr` and `gather`. [Here's one](https://rpubs.com/bradleyboehmke/data_wrangling). Then `ggplot(dat.long, aes(Year, value, colour=key)) + geom_line()`.

Comment: Thank you @eipi10! I did some clean-up that had ridden of the extra columns: `poverty2<- poverty[,3:6]`. then I tried your `gather()` method and restored it to a variable `long`. When plotted it, however, the lines are still discontinuous. I got a warning `Removed 30 rows containing missing values (geom_path).`.

Comment: You probably have missing data in some columns, causing breaks in the plotted lines. What happens if you remove missing values: `dat.long = poverty %>% gather(key, value, -Year) %>% filter(!is.na(value))`, and then plot the data.

Comment: Yes, there are NAs in my data frame. The warning says `Error in filter(., !is.na(value)) : object 'value' not found`. Also, should I use `dat.long =` or `dat.long <-`?

Comment: Never mind. I've sorted it out by using `dat.long<-dat.long[complete.cases(dat.long), ]`. Thank you all so much!

Comment: `=` vs `<-` is just a matter of personal preference.